# Spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE application do not deploy in JBoss 6.4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment, jboss

I can not deploy in jboss using the spring boot **2.0.5.RELEASE**.

*The deployment is performed correctly using 1.5.2.RELEASE*.

The error occurs during the *enabling phase*.

This is the error message provided by the JBoss console:

```
Failed to enable bacheca-service-1.0.0.war.

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "bacheca-service-1.0.0.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

These are the server logs:

```
10:53:31,364 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "bacheca-service-1.0.0.war" (runtime-name: "bacheca-service-1.0.0.war")
10:53:36,672 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015852: Could not index class module-info.class at /C:/Server/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/bacheca-service-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 24
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:665) [jandex-1.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:699) [jandex-1.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]

10:53:37,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:53:37,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:53:37,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:53:37,557 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:53:37,557 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:53:37,570 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "bacheca-service-1.0.0.war" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
10:53:37,577 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) JBAS018210: Register web context: /bacheca-ssi
10:53:37,627 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/bacheca-ssi]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) 3 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
10:53:38,059 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) 

10:53:38,059 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635)   .   ____          _            __ _ _

10:53:38,059 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \

10:53:38,059 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

10:53:38,059 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )

10:53:38,060 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

10:53:38,060 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

10:53:38,060 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635)  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

10:53:38,060 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) 

10:53:38,125 INFO  [it.inail.ssi.rest.bacheca.Application] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Starting Application on PC-SANTONINI with PID 2108 (started by Simone Antonini in C:\Server\jboss-eap-6.4\bin)
10:53:38,126 INFO  [it.inail.ssi.rest.bacheca.Application] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
10:53:38,147 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@e4d5066: startup date [Fri Oct 12 10:53:38 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
10:53:38,971 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
10:53:39,088 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$27ff858b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:53:39,136 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/bacheca-ssi]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
10:53:39,136 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 989 ms
10:53:39,494 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
10:53:39,495 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
10:53:39,495 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
10:53:39,495 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
10:53:39,496 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
10:53:39,496 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
10:53:39,637 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Using JTA UserTransaction: org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction@5ac5510b
10:53:39,637 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Using JTA TransactionManager: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate@72b0eb72
10:53:39,638 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple@594fc3c2
10:53:39,760 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
10:53:39,792 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
10:53:39,885 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
10:53:39,888 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:53:39,935 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
10:53:40,049 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
10:53:40,086 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000270: Type registration [byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@1caf84d5
10:53:40,086 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000270: Type registration [[B] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@1caf84d5
10:53:40,087 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000270: Type registration [Byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@4681ad6f
10:53:40,087 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) HHH000270: Type registration [[Ljava.lang.Byte;] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@4681ad6f
10:53:40,437 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
10:53:40,749 WARN  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
10:53:40,750 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
10:53:40,751 INFO  [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
10:53:40,760 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
10:53:40,763 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider; but it does not exist. Its class, javax.validation.Configuration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Server/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/javax/validation/api/main/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-redhat-3.jar!/javax/validation/Configuration.class
    vfs:/C:/Server/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/bacheca-service-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar/javax/validation/Configuration.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Server/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/javax/validation/api/main/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-redhat-3.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.validation.Configuration

10:53:40,764 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) JBAS018202: Error calling onStartup for servlet container initializer: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:187) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3775) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:314) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:290) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 more

10:53:40,777 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) JBAS018206: Webapp [/bacheca-ssi] is unavailable due to startup errors
10:53:40,777 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /bacheca-ssi start, will stop it
10:53:40,778 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 635) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    ... 6 more

10:53:40,782 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (HttpManagementService-threads - 24) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "bacheca-service-1.0.0.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
10:53:40,783 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 24) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "bacheca-service-1.0.0.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
10:53:41,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment bacheca-service-1.0.0.war (runtime-name: bacheca-service-1.0.0.war) in 267ms
10:53:41,052 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 24) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."bacheca-service-1.0.0.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag".START (no longer required)
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./bacheca-ssi
```

These are spring maven dependencies used:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

The war is created using the maven war plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a dependency conflict i think. Project have  javax.validation.Configuration dependency and jboss have another one. You should consider fix it via maven exclution.

Answer (score 1):

This setup might work in practice, but this is not officially supported by the Spring team.

As of Spring Framework 5 (Spring Boot 2.0 is based on that generation), [the new baseline is JDK8+ and Java EE7+](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#jdk-8-and-java-ee-7-baseline). This JBoss version is Java EE6.